# Finding duplicate records and subset for a clean dataset

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in which all the values in a particular row have duplicate rows wherein the 2nd row have missing values in it.

How can I write a code in python to find the duplicate records in a dataset?
[Original Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV6MV.png)
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDvoi.png)

Comment: please paste your input dataframe & expected output dataframe into the question (you can use HTML snippet to paste). that would be easier to test the code.

Comment: Hello @swasthika, you have mentioned about subset, can you please elaborate that one?

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard pandas question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) include the column which contains Null values

use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and provide column `FileNo`

```
df.sort_values(by=['FileNo','Coverage'],ascending=[True,True],inplace=True,na_position='last')

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['FileNo'],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas drop_duplicates() method helps in removing duplicates from the data frame.

Syntax:
*DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep=’first’, inplace=False)*

Refer for example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates/

And, Pandas dropna() method allows the user to analyze and drop Rows/Columns with Null values n different ways.

Syntax:
*DataFrameName.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)*

Refer for example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-dropna/

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='FileNo')
```